# Index out of range and the other questions aren't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
import random as rd 

numberRandomizer = 0
def addNumRandomizer(numArray):
    numberRandomizer = rd.randint(50, 100)
    for x in numArray:
        y = numArray[x] + numberRandomizer
        numArray[x] = y
    print(numArray)
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What list are you passing to the function?

Comment: what are you trying do actually ?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] including the full error message with traceback. As well, `addNumRandomizer` is never called. You can [edit] the question. See [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: What is the point of `numberRandomizer = 0` outside of the function definition? That isn't the same variable as `numberRandomizer` inside the function definition since it is in a different scope. If you would want the function call to modify `numberRandomizer` you would need to declare that variable as `global` in the function definition -- although this doesn't seem like a valid use-case for global variables.

Comment: `for x in numArray:` - this iterates the values in `numArray` (assuming its a `list`). Unless they are indexes back into thier own list, it makes no sense to  `numArray[x]`. You may want to do `for x in range(len(numArray))` - that would be the indexes into the list 0, 1, 2, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at line 7 `y = numArray[x]` look carefully what is happening. 
For exemple if you had `numArray = [1, 2, 10]` then your `x` would take the values of that array and you are indexing that same array of length 3 with the elements inside it. so that you would have something like: `numArray[10]` when `x = 10`, and clearly this is out of bounds because your are doesn't have a `10th` element but only `3`.

On possible solution is:

```
import random as rd 

numberRandomizer = 0
def addNumRandomizer(numArray):
    numberRandomizer = rd.randint(50, 100)
    for i, x in enumerate(numArray):
        y = numArray[i] + numberRandomizer
        numArray[i] = y
    print(numArray)
```

Or more easily:

```
import random as rd 

numberRandomizer = 0
def addNumRandomizer(numArray):
    numberRandomizer = rd.randint(50, 100)
    for x in range(len(numArray)):
        y = numArray[x] + numberRandomizer
        numArray[x] = y
    print(numArray)
```

Comment: in fact `numArray[3]` would fail since Python indexes from 0, i.e. the third element is at `numArray[2]`

Comment: yes also @wjandrea
I used 10 as an example for it to be more obvious because it is quite far bigger than 3

Comment: It would be cleaner to drop `y` and just use `numArray[x] += numberRandomizer`.

Comment: @JohnColeman of course.. i just fear if it doesn't give complexity to his code by giving answers to the not asked question ;-)

Comment: @moctarjallo I made that comment mostly for OP's benefit since they seem to be a beginner in Python.